Word Problem/ Exponential Growth
The deer population in Farrington Village is growing at a constant rate of 60 deer per year. Two years after Mark Mccombs moved there, the population was 340. What was the population 10 years after he moved in?
At first I calculated 940, because 60 x 10 = 600 then + 340 = 940.
But now that I review it, It should be 820. Correct?
Because two years after he moved in are already accounted for, so its asking 10 years after he initially moved in, so you would only calculate 8 years worth of growth, which 8 x 60 = 480, and + 340 = 820.

Mark moved to the village. After two years the population is $340$. Then he remains $8$ more years in the village. So he is in total $10$ years in the village. 'That means the population of the deers growth 8 additional years: $340+8\cdot 60=340+480=820$

That's linear growth, not exponential growth.

sorry for the misleading title. Thankyou guys for your help.

If it's $340$ after $2$ years, then after $8$ more years, it should be $$8 \cdot 60 + 340 = 820$$ as you correctly figured out.
